# Unable to decode gob data

Tags: go

I have a simple struct type which I am encoding. However, I am doing something fundamentally wrong while decoding the data. Every time I try to decode it, I get EOF panic error.

//Encoding a map to a gob.  Save the gob to disk. Read the gob from disk. Decode the gob into another map.
package main

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "encoding/gob"
        "bytes"
        "io/ioutil"
)

type hashinfo struct {
  fname string 
  hash string
}



func main() {

        thing := []hashinfo{
            {"rahul","test"},
            {"boya","test2"},
        }

        m := new(bytes.Buffer) 
        enc := gob.NewEncoder(m)
        enc.Encode(thing)
        err := ioutil.WriteFile("gob_data", m.Bytes(), 0600) 
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("just saved gob with %v\n", thing)


        n,err := ioutil.ReadFile("gob_data")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("cannot read file")
                panic(err)
        } 
        p := bytes.NewBuffer(n) 
        dec := gob.NewDecoder(p)
        e := []hashinfo{}
        err = dec.Decode(&e)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("cannot decode")
                panic(err)
        } 
        fmt.Printf("just read gob from file and it's showing: %v\n", e)
}
```

I have created e := []hashinfo{} object in order to decode gobject. Am I doing something wrong there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields in `type hashinfo` are not exported and cannot be deserialized. Try with `Fname` and `Hash`.

Comment: Ohh. Btw, whats the deal with variables strating with uppercase inside struct.

Comment: They are exported (visible outside the package). Work your way through the Go tour, read Effective Go and take a look at the spec.